# dataLayer.push is adding a new item instead of updating an existing one

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, google-optimize

I'm running some A/B tests with Google Optimize and am trying to just update a value in the dataLayer from my app but instead of updating it, it just adds a new object to it. According to the docs it should update if the key already exists.

Am I missing something?

For example:

```js
// initiate dataLayer at the top of <head>
window.dataLayer = [{
  message: ""
}];

// later after some stuff loaded
window.dataLayer.push({message: 'Test message'});

console.log(window.dataLayer) // added instead of updated
// [
//   {message: ""},
//   {message: "test"}
// ]
```

Comment: Keys look different in your code; one is `message`the other is  `savingsMessage`. Are you sure the output you printed actually says both keys are `message`? Anyway, `Array.prototype.push()` in javascript adds a new entry to the array. `Array.prototype.splice()` is what updates an entry. Either way it shouldn't matter because GTM will look at the key names and take the one with the higher index as the latest. If you think about it, it's preferable that they use push instead of splice, because then you have a history of events that happen on that page.

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali Thanks, yeah sorry my bad, I changed it to `message` just to simplify the example, I was using the same key for sure. (corrected example now). You're right about the history. I think I just wrongly assumed how it should work. I'm accessing the datalayer manually via javascript and I assumed that GTM customises Array push to update the value instead of adding to it, so it would always be at the same index. I've now realised I should be using `window.google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].dataLayer.get('message')` to access it and then it will always return the latest entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, and thanks to comment of @IskandarRezaRazali, it's working correctly but I should have been using `window.google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].dataLayer.get('message')` (which will always give you the latest entry) to retrieve the value rather than trying to access it via index or having to do Array.find`.

Answer (score 0):

Steven ,

Looks like you have missed the use of single quotes in your statement . In the documentation Google says

```
dataLayer.push({new-variable: 'value'});      // Won't work
```

instead

```
dataLayer.push({'new-variable': 'value'});    // Better
```

Look at the code below

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [];
  dataLayer.push({'message' : 'Test message'});
</script>
```

You can read the documentation here - https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Comment: Thanks but that's just for safety when using keys with dashes etc, it won't make a difference in this case.